# Can I use google web fonts api or any type of custom fonts in ebay?

Tags: javascript, fonts, ebay-api, google-webfonts

I'm working in a layout for an ebay store. I know that ebay have restrictions using javascript code but you can call googleapis.com with a  tag. So, Can I use google web fonts api or any type of custom fonts? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can! You can use the font API in an external CSS file, which is still allowed.

Eg:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
If you were to use the Google font - Proxima Nova, you'd:

Just add the below code at the top of your HTML code

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and then you can specify an element with the delcared font with this:

```
<span style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova';"> Sample </span>
```